# Does a point lie on a line with a parametric equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the point $(0, 5, 5)$ line on the line with the parametric equations:
$x = 3 - t\\y = 2 + t\\z = 2 + 2t$

This is the first time I see one of these, right now I assume it is as simple as solving $t$ and plugging it into the equations as such

if $x = 0$ then $t = 3$

then I plug this and get
$y = 2 + 3 = 5\\z = 2+2(3) = 8$

hence $(0, 5, 5)$ is not on the line.

Is this the correct way to solve such a problem?

Comment: That seems correct. What is your question?

Comment: I really had no idea how to solve this problem, intuition made me believe I have to do it the way I did. I just wanted to confirm that I am in fact doing the right thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct! The corresponding system (using the values for $x, y, z$ in your "test point") is inconsistent, so the "test point" fails to lie on given line. In particular, note that there is no value for $t$ that satisfies both $2 + t = 5$ and $2 + 2t = 5$.

Comment: Why is this a blank score, not now +1